# How to prevent the default suggest box from showing up?

Tags: javascript, browser

When I input some text into an input element a default suggest box shows up displaying previously entered strings. How to prevent the default suggest box from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Use autocomplete attribute with an off value.
e.g:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" autocomplete="off"/>
```